# Why is there an additional pair of curly braces on the Inno Setup Preprocessor:#emit page?

Tags: inno-setup, documentation, preprocessor, curly-braces, emit

I've been looking through Inno Setup documentation and found this:

(https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=expressions)

```
Filename: "file2.ext"; DestDir: {{#MyDestDir}}
```

Why do we need to use an additional pair of curly braces here? Mustn't we type it like this instead `DestDir: "{#MyDestDir}"`?

Comment: I believe it's a mistake. I've submitted a fix: https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/pull/347

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, that `Filename` parameter got me confused as well. I mean, there is a `Filename` parameter for the [Files] section, but it can't be used without `Source`.