# What is the point of the #emit directive in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, directive, preprocessor

Here are examples from the [`#emit` directive documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/topic_emit.htm):

> ```
> [Files]
> #emit 'Source: "file1.ext"; DestDir: {' + MyDestDir + '}'
> Source: "file2.ext"; DestDir: {#MyDestDir}
> #emit GenerateVisualCppFilesEntries ; user defined function
> ```

In the first line I don't understand the `DestDir` part. Looks like the `#` symbol is missing there.

I understand the second line. But why do we need to use the `#emit` directive like in line 1 anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Inno Setup preprocessor directives](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=directives) can be invoked using two syntaxes.

A basic syntax:

```
#directive params
```

And an inline syntax:

```
{#directive params}
```

---

On top of that, the [`#emit` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=emit) is the default *inline* directive, assumed, when no explicit directive name is specified.

---

So these three are equivalent:

```
#emit MyDestDir
```

```
{#emit MyDestDir}
```

```
{#MyDestDir}
```

Though the first does not make sense with a *path* variable, as it would result in invalid script syntax – but it can be used with a variable that contains a valid script syntax:

```
#define FileSectionEntry 'Source: ' + MySource + '; DestDir: ' + MyDestDir
#emit FileSectionEntry
```

While the other two inline examples can make sense, but only with other code on the same line, like in the code from your question:

```
Source: "file2.ext"; DestDir: {#MyDestDir}
```

---

Additionally an `#emit` with a (string) constant is basically pointless, as you can achieve the same without preprocessor.

These three are equivalent:

```
Source: "file2.ext"; DestDir: "{app}"
```

```
#emit 'Source: "file2.ext"; DestDir: "{app}"'
```

```
{#'Source: "file2.ext"; DestDir: "{app}"'}
```

---

So getting back to the code in your script, these are (almost) equivalent:

```
#emit 'Source: "file1.ext"; DestDir: {' + MyDestDir + '}'
```

```
Source: "file1.ext"; DestDir: {#MyDestDir}
```

The only problem is that I believe the curly brackets in the first line should not be there. The line should be:

```
#emit 'Source: "file1.ext"; DestDir: ' + MyDestDir
```

I have submitted a [fix for this](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/pull/388). It's basically another copy of the typo from your previous question: [Why is there an additional pair of curly braces on the Inno Setup Preprocessor:#emit page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63036551/850848)